# Dimming background around view

Tags: android, user-interface

Given an activity with multiple views, is there a way to have the background dimmed while one view retains its original state (not dimmed)?

I have an existing layout with views and I am adding a dimmed framelayout over the existing layout, and would like to keep one of the child views in the existing views "lightened up" in its state while the dimmed framelayout view encompasses around it.

Comment: I'd make that FrameLayout a custom framelayout that you can provide the bounds of the View to keep visible, and just clip the dimming to the inverse of those bounds.

Answer (score 2):

The way I know how to do this won't be very elegant for your particular use case.  But I'll explain it in case you don't find a better solution.

Wrap your entire layout in a RelativeLayout, and then add a LinearLayout with fill_parent parameters on top of it, and a partially transparent black background.  Adjust the alpha and RGB to how you see fit.

Now you can add your undimmed view to the RelativeLayout on top of the dimming.  Since you're no longer inside the FrameLayout container, you'd have to adjust the positioning of this layout, and manually remove and re-add these two views for dimming and undimming, hence this is not a very elegant solution.